# Change database file plain text to sqlite

Tags: linux, database, sqlite, utf-8

I have a sqlite db and wanted to edit by using a text editor. SO, I dumped the sqlite database file to plain text format and then edited and saved. The command I used in the terminal is,

```
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 myfile.db > myfiletext.txt
```

Here, `myfile.db` is sqlite database file and `myfiletext.txt` is the dumped text file respectively. Now, after editing, I want to change this plain text file to sqlite database format. I want help regarding that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Use shell redirection to push SQL commands back into the sqlite CLI:

`sqlite3 new.db < myfiletext.txt`